# Compréhension de 'en' dans une phrase

Tags: traduction, en

Je lis un contrat d'assurance. Il y a une section comme celle-ci:

```
LA TERRITORIALITE
S’il en est fait mention aux conditions particulières, vos garanties s’exercent:
- Toutes garanties autres que celles ci-après : ... (liste des pays)
- Responsabilité civile: ... (liste des pays)
- ....
```

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'expliquer que `en` veut dire dans `S’il en est fait mention aux conditions particulières, vos garanties s’exercent` ?

J'ai deux idées de transformation de cette phrase:

- `S’il est fait une mention de territorialité aux conditions particulières, vos garanties s’exercent`. C'est-à-dire, que si dans les conditions particulières on parle de territorialité ce point de contrat est valable et les garanties suivantes s’exècrent dans les pays suivants.
- `S’il est fait une mention de garantie aux conditions particulières, vos garanties s’exercent`. Seuls les garanties mentionnées dans les conditions particulières s’exècrent dans les pays suivants.

Laquelle est bonne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Votre deuxième idée est la bonne. Le pronom "en" est ici utilisé à la place de "vos garanties". C'est une tournure classique où l'on commence la phrase par un pronom, pour ensuite indiquer ce à quoi le pronom réfère.

La tournure equivalente est:

> Si il est fait mention de vos garanties aux conditions particulières, celles-ci s'exercent:

La signification est la même que:

> Si, dans les conditions particulières, vos garanties sont mentionnées, celles-ci s'exercent:

Dans un sens strict, cela ne signifie pas

*"Seules les garanties mentionnées dans les conditions particulières s'exercent dans les pays suivants."* (le mot "seul" indique l'exclusivité:  la phrase ainsi construite signifie donc également que toutes garanties mentionnées en dehors des conditions particulières ne s'exercent pas dans les pays suivants)

...mais plutôt...

*"Si des garanties sont mentionnées dans les conditions particulières, alors ces garanties s'exercent dans les pays suivants:"*